# multi indices Elasticsearch query in golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl, glide-golang

Hy, I am facing problem during creation of search query for multi indices in Elasticsearch. I have two indices one is "files" having field "filename" and other indices is "message" having field "messageid".I want to get result base on both indices where filename="any stored name in els" from files indices and  messageid="any store id in ELS". I want this search in single query.

trying to search ELS query base on multi indices.

Answer (score 0):

The indices in the URL of a search request in elasticsearch specify the indices to search within. You can search within one or more indices by [specifying the indices in the URL of the search request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multiple-indices.html#search-multiple-indices).

To search for documents that match a specific phrase in the `filename` field of the `files` index or the `messageid` field of the `message` index, you can use the `match_phrase` query within a bool query with a should clause.
This allows you to search for documents that match either of the queries, while only returning exact matches for the specified phrases.

Here is an example:

```
POST /files,message/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "filename": "any stored name in els"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "messageid": "any stored id in ELS"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This search request will return all documents that contain the exact phrase "any stored name in els" in the filename field of the `files` index, or the exact phrase "any stored id in ELS" in the messageid field of the `message` index.

This is how it can be achieved in Golang:

```
query := elasticsearch.NewBoolQuery().Should(
    elasticsearch.NewMatchPhraseQuery("filename", "any stored name in els"),
    elasticsearch.NewMatchPhraseQuery("messageid", "any stored id in ELS"),
)

searchResult, err := client.Search().
    Index("files", "message").
    Query(query).
    Do(context.Background())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
I want to get result when both condition must fulfil (i.e.  `filename` field of the `files` index and `messageid` field of the `message index` both must true). So, for it should I need to use `must` keyword instead of `should` in the query?   
Secondly, I have list of `messageids` against single filename. How Can I pass list of message in multi indices query with filename.